# Get data from GROUP BY clause where COUNT returns just 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+-------+-----+
| User  | Rol |
+-------+-----+
| user1 | r1  |
| user1 | r2  |
| user1 | r3  |
| user3 | r1  |
| user3 | r5  |
| user4 | r4  |
| user5 | r2  |
+-------+-----+
```

A group by / count would return:

```sql
select User, count(Rol) as 'RolCount' 
from 
  table 
group by User;
```

```
+-------+----------+
| User  | RolCount |
+-------+----------+   
| user1 |        3 |
| user3 |        2 |
| user4 |        1 |
| user5 |        1 |
+-------+----------+
```

Is it possible to show the rol name for the records `having count(Rol) = 1` in the same sql statement? Like so:

```
+-------+----------+-----+
| User  | RolCount | Rol |
+-------+----------+-----+
| user4 |        1 | r4  |
| user5 |        1 | r2  |
+-------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: use `MIN(Rol)` or `MAX(Rol)` since there is only one occurrence, `min()` or `max()` will give you the same value

Comment: Side point: if `Rol` is not nullable, then `COUNT(Rol)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE(USERR,ROL)AS 
 (
    SELECT 'user1' , 'r1'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user1'  ,'r2'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user1'  ,'r3'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user3'  ,'r1'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user3'  ,'r5'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user4'  ,'r4'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user5'  ,'r2'
 )
 SELECT C.USERR,COUNT(C.USERR)CNTT,MAX(C.ROL)ROL
   FROM CTE AS C
    GROUP BY C.USERR
      HAVING COUNT(C.USERR)=1
```

Based on the above comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to do it:

```
with aggt(usr, count_rol)as
(
    select usr, count(rol)  from t group by usr
)
select usr
    , count_rol
    , iif(count_rol=1,(select top(1) ROL from t where t.usr=aggt.usr),'')
from aggt
```

I included `top(1)`, but I tried it without, and that works as well.